# Building a webservice with XML?

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, web-services, api

XML Webservice: the webservices takes in an XML request and responses with a XML response.

im not sure if im doing the right thing for the request?

With the XML request, do i take the XML request from the page input parameter?

Example

```
http://api.domain.com/webservice/xmlExample1.aspx?xml=<Example1><FirstName>David</FirstName></Example>
```

<-- XML Request **(this looks very wrong)**

response

```
<Example1Response>
<Success>True</Success>
</Example1Response>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Typically* you would handle that as a POST (not a GET), and read the xml from the request-stream (or there are helpers to let you do this). Otherwise URL encoding and length restrictions are going to make this **extremely** painful.